# React styling/component not showing (MS Fabric UI)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, office-ui-fabric

I have a list that I want to style with Microsoft fabrics react "list" component as seen here:

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/components/list

(the one with the "Rendering ghost items while the list is scrolling" header).

I try to follow the examples and do the folowing:

```
 import { List } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/List';
  import { Image, ImageFit } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Image';


 return (


  <div>


      { listItems.length > 0 && listItems.map((item: Project) => {

        return (


           <div>


        <div  data-is-focusable={true}  className="ms-ListGhostingExample- 
   itemCell">
     <Image 
     className="ms-ListGhostingExample-itemImage"
              src={item.ListUrl.substring(0, item.ListUrl.indexOf("/Lists")) + "/_api/GroupService/GetGroupImage?id" }
              width={50}
              height={50}
              imageFit={ImageFit.cover}

          />  

          <div className="ms-ListGhostingExample-itemContent">
          <div className="ms-ListGhostingExample-itemName"> <a  href={item.ListUrl.substring(0, item.ListUrl.indexOf("/Lists"))}>{item.Title}</a></div>

           </div></div>
           </div>


        );
      })}
      </div>
```

While I don't get any (syntax) errors, no styling is applied at all. Why does it not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [*Rendering ghost items while the list is scrolling* example](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/components/list) via the following reference:

`imports import './List.Ghosting.Example.scss';`

the expected styling is applied per  a `List` component. In your case those styles could be applied like this:

```
import 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/components/List/examples/List.Ghosting.Example.scss';
```